# Unable to create a trigger in mysql hosted on amazon cloud

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, triggers

When am trying to create a simple trigger in mysql, am encountering the below error message. Please suggest me how to overcome this.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger trg_addresses_ins before insert on addresses
for each row
begin
   declare msg varchar(128);
     if length(new.addressstate) > 2 then
        set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert a state value of more than 2 character: ', new.addressstate);
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
end if;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

`

Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)    0.078 sec

Super user is enabled but still get the same error and also am unable to change database parameter group associated with mysql aws db instance to 1. I am unable to modify db instance to select newly created group as the parameter group field is read only.

[image]

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using the default DB parameter group which you can not modify, the solution is you need to create your own parameter group, and set `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1`, and apply your own parameter group to your current instance.

Comment: I created the new parameter group but am unable to change the default group to this new one as this field in settings is read only

Comment: @Dex you don't change the default group.  You change your instance to use the new group.  This will require a reboot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I understand that I need to modify instance to use the new group but the thing is parameter group is read only so am unable to modify the instance.

Comment: A new parameter group should not be read-only. The point of creating one is so you can modify it.